# How can I Unwrap this high poly model?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I am trying to UV unwrap this high poly model, however it is not working correctly.I tried putting seams on various edge loops but didn't work. Although, by looking at the UV Map, it looks somewhat fine to me, however the texture looks so messy. Plz Help!

-Base Model

[image]

-Resulting UV map using SmartUVProject

[image]

-Checker Texture Applied based on the above uv map

[image]

Comment: Have you tried cylinder projection? Just make sure you are in an orthogonal frontal view

Comment: No i haven't yet, i m gonna try.

Comment: It worked Oh Man Thank You so so much, Appreciate it so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the *Cylinder Projection* mode, just make sure that you are in an orthogonal frontal view.

Comment: It worked Oh Man Thank You so so much, Appreciate it so much

Comment: However,using cylinder projection, I am getting a seam in the texture at the back of the model but that seam is invisible in Checker Map, why is this so??

Comment: you'll always get a visual seam unless you use a repeatable pattern or a procedural texture, I don't know why you don't see it on the checker map though

Comment: Oh ok i c, got it.